# Lost computer with bitcoins

Tags: client

I had purchased bitcoins several years ago.  I installed the version of this software that was available at the time and I think everything was saved on the computer I was using it at that time.  The computer that had my bitcoins on it has disappeared.  I am installing the latest version of the Bitcoin Core wallet now but how would I go about getting my bitcoins back.

I couldn't seem to find an exact answer on how to restore my bitcoins.

Comment: to less info to provide precise answer: you don't mention type of OS, nor where you purchased, or which wallet you used (looks like bitcoin core), if you where mining... On unixoide systems, maybe you had a backup of your home directory, then it would contain a folder named ".bitcoin", with a file named "wallet.dat". That's probably all you need... If there is no backup, and you haven't written down the private key, then you are nearly lost. Sure you didn't use an online wallet?

Answer (score 3):

If the computer "disappeared", there is no way to get your Bitcoins other than finding the computer again.

You had a "wallet.dat" file on the there which stores the information necessary to access your Bitcoins. Without it you cannot access your Bitcoins.